# Calcular a média entre várias datas em uma array

Tags: php

Estou precisando calcular uma média não só entre uma data inicial e uma data final, mas em todas as datas presentes em uma matriz para obter um resultado médio em dias, horas, minutos e segundos de quanto X em X tempo tal evento é registrado.

Já desenvolvi uma base para este cálculo mas não me parece estar correto, pois vejamos no exemplo:

```
$dates = ['2015-05-10 12:00:00', '2015-05-11 12:00:00', '2015-05-12 12:00:00'];
$dates = array_map('strtotime', $dates);

for($count = count($dates), $result = 0, $i = 1; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    $result += $dates[$i-1] - $dates[$i];
}

$seconds = floor($result / $count);

$DTF = new DateTime("@0");
$DTT = new DateTime("@$seconds");
echo $DTF->diff($DTT)->format('%a dias, %h horas, %i minutos e %s segundos');
```

No array, a diferença entre estas 3 datas são de exatamente 24 horas, porém o resultado desde cálculo é: `0 dias, 16 horas, 0 minutos e 0 segundos`, o que poderia está errado?

Comment: O resultado esperado é?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque no final do loop `$result` armazenou as duas diferenças (24 + 24 = 48 horas) mas dividiu pela quantidade de índices (3).

O correto seria `$seconds = floor($result / $count - 1)` pois embora você tenha 3 datas, possui apenas 2 intervalos entre elas.

Comment: Verdade, cheguei a este mesmo resultado a pouco, é exatamente isto!